# Parse JSON with newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, json.net

I am getting json response from this google api service to get reverse geo location from lat and long.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true

In the response JSON there are lot of rack [] of same names. How I can parse this JSON with newtonsoft to get country name.

Comment: As linkerro said: [What have you tried yourself?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @linkerro: If I didnt get answers then how I accepts as answer and improve my rate? People like you just can shout but cant answer..

Comment: If you're not getting answers, it may be worthwhile to look at improving your question quality.  This might help: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var json = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(wc.DownloadString(url));

var country = json["results"]
                .SelectMany(x => x["address_components"])
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t["types"].First().ToString() == "country");

var name = country!=null ? country["long_name"].ToString() : "";
```